# How can I get off "hold" and what does it indicate?

Tags: discussion

I posted https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/33029/bike-mystery-nice-lightweight a few days ago ...

I have responded to the requests of some people but am still on "hold". Why?

Comment: This is a question for meta.SE, not bicycles.SE. It takes 5 re-open votes for someone to re-open your question.

Comment: The way things work is that it takes five votes from people with 3000 rep to close or reopen a question, or one vote from a moderator. At present you have three reopen votes. Perhaps adding the kind of photo Daniel asked for would help get those votes.

Comment: See the [help] for more information.

Answer (score 2):

The comments sum up why it wasn't immediately taken off hold, but I'll give you a little more info.

When you edited the question, it went into a review queue for mods and users with 3000+ [reputation](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). If one mod or five regular users votes to reopen it, it gets reopened. As it happens, I'm both a mod and the fifth person to vote to reopen. So you're good to go again.

Incidentally, I also made some edits for clarity. Feel free to edit it further if you feel that my edits detract from your question.